# Why this constant $c$ is the determinant of the operator

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading [Linear Algebra written by Kenneth M Hoffman and Ray Kunze](http://uap.unnes.ac.id/ebook/mathematics%20ebook/Algebra/Linear%20Algebra,%202nd%20ed%20-%20Kenneth%20Hoffman,%20Ray%20Kunze,%201971.pdf)
 and on page 172 he states the following corollary:

[image]

Afterwards, he said that:

> Of course, the element $c$ in the last corollary is called the determinant of $T$.

I simply don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

If we choose a basis $v_1, \dots, v_n$ for $V$ and write $Tv_j = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} v_i$ then

$$ L(Tv_1, \dots, Tv_n) = L \left( \sum_{i_{1}=1}^n a_{i_{1},1} v_{i_1}, \dots, \sum_{i_n=1}^n a_{i_n,n} v_{i_n} \right) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} a_{\sigma(1),1} \dots a_{\sigma(n),n} L(v_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, v_{\sigma(n)}) = \\
\left( \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} (-1)^{\sigma} a_{\sigma(1),1} \dots a_{\sigma(n),n} \right) L(v_1, \dots, v_n) = \det(T) L(v_1, \dots, v_n).$$